# How to enable the record for delete after retrieve in sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I fetch record from database using following code.

```
 for (LocWiseProfileBeans cn : LocWiseProfile) {
        // get a reference for the TableLayout
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.locprofile_table);

        // create a new TableRow
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        // count the counter up by one
        counter++;


        String log = "Loc Name: "+cn.getLocname()+" ,Lattitude: " + cn.getLattitude()+ " ,Longitude: " + cn.getLongitude()+ " , Selected Profile :"+cn.getSelectedprofile();
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        // set the text to "text xx"
        t.setText(cn.getLocname());

        TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
        t2.setText(cn.getSelectedprofile());
        row.addView(t);
        row.addView(t2);
        table.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But i need to enable this record for deletion on user request.
Means if user click on second record then this record will be delete.
I try to find the answer but not find any appropriate answer.......
Please provide me reference code or article.
Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Probably you can use ListView to display the result?

Comment: which view should i use for enable the record? thanks

Comment: @raju: If user click on any record then it should be deleted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting onClickListener to your row.
To determine which row is clicked, you can set a unique tag to that row.

```
row.setTag(counter);  //  use counter or index for tag, so you can get the data from LocWiseProfile later
row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)  {
        int tag = (Integer)view.getTag();
        LocWiseProfileBeans cn = LocWiseProfile.get(tag);
        //  Perform delete action here
        //  ...
    }   
});
```

If you want to simply display the result from db as a list, I suggest you using ListActivity or ListView, with using adapter you can show and manage your data in more simple way.

Comment: But how to set this tag value to specific row. i use your logic but it delete only top row not selected row. give me one favor again...thanks

Comment: You set tag to all rows.  Usually use the row index as its tag, so when you later using get tag, the value of the tag is the row index. So you can use this index to handle delete content. But one thing is that you have to update the tag after you delete the row, because the data list has changed. If you use ListView/ListActivity, the adapter will help you to manage this change.

Comment: row.setTag(counter);  //  use counter or index for tag, so you can get the data from LocWiseProfile later
            row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
     try{
     int tag = (Integer)v.getTag();
     LocWiseProfileBeans cn = LocWiseProfile.get(tag);
           if(tag==cn.getId()) 
           {
      m.delete(cn.getId());
      deleteMessage();
           }
     }catch(Exception e){}
           is this right?

Answer (score 1):

```
    //decleration 
EventDataSQLHelper eventsData; //Class where table is created
SQLiteDatabase dbx,rdbx;

//onCreate
eventsData = new EventDataSQLHelper(this);
rdbx= eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
        dbx=eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//specify the id of the record to be deleted
            dbx.delete("tablename", "id=" ?, null); 
            }
        });
```